# Is there a simpler approach to store tic-tac-toe state as an integer using binary literals?

Tags: python, numpy, binary

The following code allows me to persist the complete tic-tac-toe state as a single integer by converting the numpy array to a binary string. Each cell can be 0, 1 or 2 and therefore keeps 2 bits to represent them and then I concatenate them somehow.

```py
import numpy as np

def convert_to_int(state):
    binary = "0b"

    for x in range(0, state.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, state.shape[1]):
            binary += format(state[x, y].item(), '02b')

    return int(binary, 0)


def convert_to_numpy(state):
    cells = []

    binary_string = "{0:b}".format(state).zfill(18)

    for i in range(0, len(binary_string), 2):
        cells.append(int(binary_string[i: i + 2], 2))

    return np.array(cells).reshape((3, 3))

input_state = np.array((
    (1, 2, 1),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0)),
    dtype="int32")

state_as_int = convert_to_int(input_state)
output_state = convert_to_numpy(state_as_int)

print(state_as_int)
print(output_state)
```

```
102400

[[1 2 1]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]
```

How can I simplify the code. Is there a way to use only binary literals and bitwise operators without using string conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question.  I have been ignoring numpy, and this problem is an excuse to learn.

This answer uses shifting to convert to integer and vice versa.

```
import numpy as np

def convert_to_int(state):
    a = 0
    for num in state.reshape(9):
        a = a + num
        a = a << 2
    return a
    
def convert_state_to_numpy(state):
    cells = []
    for i in range(9) :
        state >>= 2
        cells.insert(0,(3 & state))
     
    return np.array(cells).reshape((3,3))

input_state = np.array((
    (1, 2, 1),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0)),
    dtype="int32")

state_as_int = convert_to_int(input_state)
output_state = convert_state_to_numpy(state_as_int)

print(hex(state_as_int))
print(output_state)
```

Comment: Btw. Could you explain why 3 (3&state) is the correct number to make it working?

Comment: 3 & state peels off the low order 2 bits of the integer. e.g. 0011 & xxyy = 00yy. Then shift right 2 and repeat

Answer (score 1):

Instead of each cell as a 32bit integer you could use two integers and store the positions as bit flags. Say for example:

```
Os = 0b000100000
Xs = 0b100000001

X _ _
_ _ O
_ _ X
```

Comment: Though it's not my question. It could help others. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun problem. Here's what I came up with:

```py
import numpy as np

def convert_to_int(state):
    binary = 0b0

    for x in range(3):
        for y in range(3):
            binary <<= 2
            binary += state[x, y].item()

    return binary

def convert_to_numpy(state):
    return np.array([(state & (2**(2*i + 1) + 2**(2*i))) >> 2*i for i in range(8, -1, -1)]).reshape(3, 3)
```

This should avoid the string conversion, and is hopefully a tad bit faster (though I didn't do any benchmarks).

I wonder if there's away to store numbers of any base in python, since you could store this as a 9 bit number in base 3...

Comment: h/t to you for getting list comprehension to work for convert_to_numpy.  Wonder if convert to int could also be a list comprehension?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Even your solution is a bit faster and working well. I rather enjoy the variant with more readability.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by a previous comment about using base 3 numbers.  Since your original question was looking for a way to compress a 3x3 array into a single integer, I will assume that you want to reduce the size of the data.  The following code takes your array which may be viewed as a 9 digit base 3 number and converts it to 15 bit integer. This number is stored as an array of 2 bytes. This may be beyond the scope of your original question but, i think, it follows the spirit of the question.

```
import numpy as np

def encode_state(state):
    a=0
    for i,num in enumerate(state.reshape(9)) :
        a = a + 3**i * int(num)
    return a.to_bytes(2,'big')

def decode_state(byte): 
    encoded_value = int.from_bytes(byte,'big')
    b = [0 for i in range(9)]
    for i in range(9) :
        num = (encoded_value // 3**i) % 3
        b[i] = num
    return np.array(b).reshape(3,3) 
input_state = np.array((
    (2, 2, 2),
    (1, 2, 2),
    (2, 1, 0)),
    dtype="int32")

state_as_byte = encode_state(input_state)
output_state = decode_state(state_as_byte)

print (''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in state_as_byte))
print(output_state)
```